How do channels / feature maps end up with differing weights in a CNN?
My understanding is that each channel will get the same input as the other channels?
So my question is, what is the mechanism by which they will form different weights and thus detect features in the image? Mathematically, wouldn't they all process in the same way on the training data?

ok, after more research, I think I found the answer. It is because of random initialization. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/292477
